# Why is Windows 10 Enterprise Shell Launcher giving a black screen?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise, Build 10586, in a Virtual Box VM to try out creating a kiosk using Windows 10.

The kiosk mode application is "cmd.exe", as a test for now.  This is for a traditional .Net application, ***not*** a Universal Windows Application.

I have found articles on SO already indicating how to do this, and I believe I have followed the breadcrumbs correctly, but I am getting a black screen whenever I boot the VM after running the script below:

```
$COMPUTER = "localhost"
$NAMESPACE = "root\standardcimv2\embedded"
$ACCOUNT_NAME = "Fred"

$ShellLauncherClass = [wmiclass]"\\$COMPUTER\${NAMESPACE}:WESL_UserSetting"


$NTUserObject = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($ACCOUNT_NAME)
$NTUserSID = $NTUserObject.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value

$NTUser_Shell = Get-WmiObject -namespace $NAMESPACE -computer $COMPUTER -class WESL_UserSetting | 
    where {$_.Sid -eq $NTUserSID}

if ($NTUser_Shell) {
    "`Custom shell already set for [$ACCOUNT_NAME] removing it"
    $ShellLauncherClass.RemoveCustomShell($NTUserSID)
}

$restart_shell = 0
$restart_device = 1
$shutdown_device = 2

$ShellLauncherClass.SetCustomShell($NTUserSID, "cmd.exe", ($null), ($null), $restart_device)

"`nCurrent settings for custom shells:"
Get-WmiObject -namespace $NAMESPACE -computer $COMPUTER -class WESL_UserSetting | Select Sid, Shell, DefaultAction

$ShellLauncherClass.SetEnabled($TRUE)
#$ShellLauncherClass.SetEnabled($FALSE)

""
"Enabled is set to " + $ShellLauncherClass.IsEnabled().Enabled
```

When I run the script in Power Shell (as an admin), everything looks right (see below).

[image]

When I reboot and log in **using any account** (admin or non-admin), I get a non-interactive black screen (i.e. just a black screen, not a command prompt).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System and set the DWORD value EnableLUA to 0

Comment: Disabling LUA is not recommended due to security reasons. More about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-lua-settings-enablelua

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have enable the Shell Launcher without Enabling the feature, or you enabled the feature, enabled the Shell Launcher, then disabled the feature.  Try running the Powershell script:

```
# To Get Optional Features   -online means the running copy of Windows
# Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online

# the -all says enable all features required by the feature to be added
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName Client-EmbeddedShellLauncher -all
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue as you today. After a lot of trying and debugging, in my case the PC wasn't upgraded to Windows 10 Enterprise. Which is necessary to use the Kiosk Mode.

Didn't get any error messages when configuring, but a blank screen instead of the .exe.

regards,
Stijn